# Javascript - Effect of assigning empty object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

JavaScript Learner - please help understand ,

In the below JS snippet, when a "nickname" property is added to object person1, it reflects in Person object as well.

But, when person1 is set to an empty object {} , please help understand why it does not affect person object?

---

```
var person  = {
  "firstname" : "Tony",
  "lastname" : "Stark"
};

var person1 = person;

person1.nickname = "Ironman";

console.log(person); 
//Object { firstname: "Tony", lastname: "Stark", nickname: "Ironman" }
console.log(person1);
//Object { firstname: "Tony", lastname: "Stark", nickname: "Ironman" }  

person1 = {};

console.log(person);
//Object { firstname: "Tony", lastname: "Stark", nickname: "Ironman" }  
console.log(person1);
//Object {  }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the below JS snippet, when a "nickname" property is added to object
>   person1, it reflects in Person object as well.

You do `person1 = person` so, now both variables point to the same memory address so varying one will reflect in the other too.

> But, when person1 is set to an empty object {} , please help
>   understand why it does not affect person object?

By doing `person1 = {}`, you're assigning it a *new* memory address so `person` and `person1` are now two different entities and changing one will not affect the other.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your time!  Able to relate about your explanation above on {} assigning a new memory address, but, assigning null or undefined to Person1 as well does not affect the Person object - Any hints why?

Answer (score 0):

`Objects` basically referenced during the time it get assigned to another one variable. So when you affect one `object` stored in a variable, it would affect the other variable too, Since both are sharing same references.

And when you are replacing a reference with another one value, the older reference will be cut off and the new `object` with new memory reference will be stored.